# Equivalent of ComputeIfAbsent in Java 7

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to run a piece of code only if the key doesn't exist in a `ConcurrentHashMap`, and save the code's result to the collection?

I can't use **Java 8** features because I'm developing for Android.

Also, I would like to avoid running long operations if I don't have to and I don't want to break the collection's atomic operation to do so.

Comment: Is there something about `if(!map.containsKey(key))` that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Zircon computeIfAbsent inserts the result of the function as the new value for that key atomically.  So that isn't a 100% replacement without extra work.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis He explicitly says he wants it to be atomic.  So no, there is no equivalent.  You can write an equivalent, but it requires you to do your own locking with an explicit semaphore.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, the piece code yields a value that will be added to the collection.

Comment: Android has these methods... [ConcurrentHashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) - Added in API 1

Comment: @cricket_007 The type was, not the methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Referring to title "equivalent of computeIfAbsent", though, I think "Added in API 1" is wrong, obviously because Java 8 was added until more recent API

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent, but the usual approach is something like this:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key,Value> map = ...

Value computeIfAbsent(Key k) {
  Value v = map.get(k);
  if (v == null) {
    Value vNew = new Value(...); // or whatever else you do to compute the value
    v = (v = map.putIfAbsent(k, vNew)) == null ? vNew : v;
  }
  return v;
}
```

This is pretty much functionally equivalent the `computeIfAbsent` call in Java 8, with the only difference being that sometimes you construct a `Value` object that never makes it into the map - because another thread put it in first. It never results in returning the wrong object or anything like that - the function consistently returns the right `Value` no matter what, but *if the construction of Value has side-effects**, this may not be acceptable.

The extra instances are generally not a performance problem because the initial `get()` check eliminates most of the calls to `putIfAbsent`. In general this approach can be considerably *faster* than `computeIfAbsent` because that call does unnecessary locking of objects when the object already exists. Locally I measured it as 5 *times* faster if there are some objects that are heavily contended.

If you really need the computing behavior integrated into the map (with an internal lock held so exactly one thread creates the new object), you can use Guava's [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) to get a `LoadingCache`. It's essentially the same behavior as Java 8's CHM, but with a ton of additional configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  The way to make it work is to use your own locking on top of the map.