# Find word frequency from huge text file using self-balancing immutable Binary Search Tree in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand how I may implement a BST that would read huge text files and store the frequency of every word in Java? I'm also trying to make it work in a multi-threaded way, so I believe I'd have to make it thread-safe as well!

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. But I'm looking for Java code wherein we construct the BST as well as add the mentioned functionality, without libraries.

Comment: "thread-safe", not "immutable"

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `ConcurrentMap` from String to `AtomicInteger` or [`LongAdder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html). Add the word the first time they are found and increment the integer after that. In Java 8, you can use `computeIfAbsent` to do this as a 1-liner, or in earlier versions you can use `putIfAbsent`. In either case, however it's best to check if the count object already exists with a `get` call first, since the methods that can modify the map are slower - even if they don't add to the map. If the initial fast-path `get()` returns no existing element you proceed to the `...ifAbsent` call:

```
    for (String word : words) {
        AtomicInteger count = chm.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            if ((count = chm.putIfAbsent(word, new AtomicInteger(1))) == null) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }
```

This will be fast and concurrent. You can split the file into chunks at the top level, and process each chunk on a different thread.

That's if you insist on a shared structure for counting. It would likely be faster to simple have each thread keep its count in a private `HashMap` and then just reduce the per thread results at the end by summing the maps.

Comment: Good point, I forgot that this is available now. In this particular case it would probably be a win for heavily contended words (think about "the"). For many words it probably wouldn't pay off as the increased size and slightly slower add operation would be worse than the small amount on contention. This problem is really a poster child for not having a shared structure at all (unless your professor requires it for an assignment).

Comment: @dnault - added `LongAdder` to the answer

Comment: You shouldn't need anything before a call to `putIfAbsent(key, value)` (your post contains a typo, there) - I can't see how (without additional locking) a preceding e.g. `get()` helps, anyway. The "obvious" way should be [`compute(key, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Comment: @greybeard The last `get` was redundant - don't know why I put that. The first `get` on the other hand is _functionally_ redundant for good performance. Unfortunately, `putIfAbsent`, despite returning the old value, doesn't seem designed to replace the first get - it unconditionally goes into the complex "put" logic, including taking lock(s), even if the element is ultimately found (see `CHM.putVal()`). So you lose most of the benefits of the contention-free `get` by using `putIfAbsent` instead. It may have gotten somewhat better in Java 8 with the CHM redesign, but a lock is still taken.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment should read: "the first `get` on the hand is _functionally_ redundant, but required for good performance". Now, about `compute()` - I have done most my recent concurrency work on Java 7 which doesn't have such handy methods. I suspect just a single `compute()` call is in general going to perform badly in the same way (or perhaps worse, as a very brief check indicated additional points where locks are taken). A reasonable approach would be a `get` followed by `computeIfAbsent` if the `get` returns nothing.

Comment: There's no race condition around ConcurrentHashMapMap.computeIfAbsent(). You don't need to call `get` or `putIfAbsent`. Just call `concurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(k -> new LongAdder()).increment()`. Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @dnault please see my comments above. I'm not claiming `putIfAbsent` or `computeIfAbsent` is racy, or that the `get` is functionally necessary. I'm saying that _the `*ifAbsent` calls are slow for successful gets_ - because they lock unconditionally. They are evidently designed to be used in the case the _element likely does not exist_. In the case the element likely exists (almost certainly the case for an example like this), you are much better off calling `get` followed by `putIfAbsent`. I've been there, done that, benchmarked it.

Comment: About `putIfAbsent` vs `computeIfAbsent`. Evidently the latter is better if you are on a version of Java that offers it! The OP hasn't specified his version, so I included both options above. Last time I checked, probably the biggest single Java-API using environment didn't have it yet: [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615431/equivalent-of-computeifabsent-in-java-7).

Comment: @BeeOnRope Well I'll be damned. Looks like you're right; stepping through with a debugger shows ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent hitting a synchronized block every time. Thanks for spreading the word.

Comment: @dnault - well yeah, although there are some possible reasons for this design (i.e., it may be faster to do it this way when the element almost always needs to be added). At least it got better in JDK 8 - in JDK 7 the lock acquired was the _segment lock_, which may be heavily contended, even if element contention is slow. In JDK 8, the segments disappeared and the lock acquired is the per-element node lock, so contention will be less unless there is actual same-element contention.

Comment: @dnault - I wrote a [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/11b4688d6f642c334927aa56ebf065a6) to test the Java 8 behavior (I already tested Java 7 and things can easily be order-of-magnitude-worse if you skip the first `get()`. The situation better in Java 8. When I artificially increase contention by adding the word "the" between every real word from my input file, the `computeIfAbsent` call is something like 3 to 5 _times_ worse than the alternatives. Also, `LongAdder` is about 40% faster than `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: On the real wordlist however, "the" makes up only about 5% of all words and the performance is closer: the benchmark is a bit noisy so it's hard to draw exact conclusions, but it looks like `computeIfAbsent` is "only" about 20% slower. Also, with a single thread (so no contention), I get runtimes of about 1100 ms for `get -> put` and 1300 ms for `computeIfAbsent`, roughly in-line with the 20% observed for the contended-but-not-terribly case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should split your file into chunks, process each chunk with not-thread-safe alghorithm on a different thread and then merge results. You will not suffer from synchronization penalty.
Or just use single thread cause bottleneck is not processor but is hard disk.

Comment: Anyone considering serious use or benchmarking should include this.

Answer (score 0):

A self-balancing tree isn't immutable by definition.

You could look up [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or another one from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Implementations).

However, I recommend another approach: Use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store the words. It will save a lot of space and will be much faster than a binary search tree.

Comment: A trie _may_ noticeably save space.